# Pthread create is not starting the thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I’m using pthread to start a thread, but the create function itself is not starting the thread
But instead if i call pthread join, it starts so actually should i call p thread join?

i heard from some answers that pthread join is not required , my pthread create function is called from main

```
    int main(void) {
    
        printf("-----------Welcome------\n");
    
        Start_Generation();
    
    
        return 0;
    }
    
   
    
    int Start_Generation(void)
    {
        
        ret=pthread_create(&C_AO_GENERATION_THREAD, NULL, C_Aogeneration_thread,(void*) message1);
        if(ret!=0)
        {
            printf("Error Starting Thread\n");
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("AO Thread Started\n");
        }
        //ret=pthread_join(C_AO_GENERATION_THREAD, NULL);
        return 0;
    }
    void *C_Aogeneration_thread (void *ptr)
    {
        char *message;
        message = (char *) ptr;
        unsigned int prof_gen_count;
        unsigned int written_sample=0;
        unsigned int curr_idx=0;
        int ch=0;
        int written=0;
        printf("%s",message);
        printf(" Generation Started\n");
        prof_gen_count=(samplingrate/10);
        
while(stopflag)
{
printf("Thread is working\n");
}
    
        return 0;
    }

    enter code here
```

Comment: That is too much code. Alot of it is not relevant to the actual question. Please reduce to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But the problem is that the main thread will exit and also terminate the child thread if `pthread_join` (or some other code to keep the main thread alive) is not called.

Comment: 700+ lines of uncompilable (for us) code is *not* a [mcve]. If `pthread_create` fails to create a thread on your environment it should be easily demonstrable in about a dozen lines of code *total*. And I concur with your friend: I see no need for threading in this application.

Comment: so if i add pthreadjoin, it will keep my main thread alive as well as my sub thread unless stop flag is set ? Other than setting stop flag to stop the thread, should i do anything else to stop the C_Aogeneration_thread ? is there any pthreadstop or exit?

Comment: @WhozCraig this application needs multi threading as there will be multiple such tasks which will need to be independent and sorry for the bad formatting i have edited

Answer (score 3):

> I’m using pthread to start a thread, but the create function itself is not starting the thread

As presented in the question, your main thread terminates by returning from `main` immediately after reporting on the success or failure of the `pthread_create()` call, so

1. the whole program terminates at that point, apparently before the child progresses far enough to present any evidence that it is running, but also
2. there is no point in using a separate thread.

> But instead if i call pthread join, it starts so actually should i call p thread join?

A call to `pthread_join()` does not return successfully until the specified thread has terminated.  That is, in fact, its purpose.  As a rule of thumb, you should either join or detach every thread you create.  Joining is usually what you want, and note, too, that detaching a thread does not prevent the process from terminating and taking that thread with it when the main thread returns or `exit()`s.